# gzclient: segmentation fault

Tags: ros, gazebo

I have archlinux indigo ros.
My probelm is that when I type in terminal:

```
$ gzclient
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

...

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
    ... logging to /home/islam/.ros/log/0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9/roslaunch-CatchMe-11800.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

    started roslaunch server http://localhost:44337/

    SUMMARY
    ========

    PARAMETERS
     * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
     * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/indigo/s...
     * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
     * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
     * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
     * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
     * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
     * /rosdistro: indigo
     * /rosversion: 1.11.20
     * /use_sim_time: True

    NODES
      /
        bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
        cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
        depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
        gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
        gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
        laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
        mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
        robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
        spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

    auto-starting new master
    process[master]: started with pid [11824]
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

    setting /run_id to 0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9
    process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11837]
    started core service [/rosout]
    process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [11852]
    process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [11861]
    process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [11868]
    process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [11873]
    process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [11878]
    process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [11880]
    process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [11882]
    process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-9]: started with pid [11896]
    process[depthimage_to_laserscan-10]: started with pid [11905]
    /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient: line 25: 11916 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) GAZEBO_MASTER_URI="$desired_master_uri" gzclient $final
    [gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 11861, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/islam/.ros/log/0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9/gazebo_gui-3.log].
    log file: /home/islam/.ros/log/0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9/gazebo_gui-3*.log
    /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver: line 30: 11978 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) GAZEBO_MASTER_URI="$desired_master_uri" gzserver $final
    [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 11852, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/islam/.ros/log/0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9/gazebo-2.log].
    log file: /home/islam/.ros/log/0f56780c-18b0-11e7-966d-642737d9d3b9/gazebo-2*.log
```

and here is the output of debug:

```
Reading symbols from gzserver...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffd4e6d700 (LWP 16809)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd038d700 (LWP 16810)]

Thread 1 "gzserver" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff2838390 in gazebo::event::Connection::Id() const ()
from /usr/lib/libgazebo_common.so.8
```

My GPU is intel HD3000 , core i5 INSPIRON N5110. I have noted that [intel hd3000 works with gazebo](http://answers.ros.org/question/63413/gazebo-crashes-when-starting/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that Gazebo 8 is based on Qt5 instead of Qt4. The dependencies should be updated and most importantly, we need to install qwt-qt5 instead of qwt, otherwise our executable is linked to both Qt4 and Qt5 which leads to segmentation fault at start.
>
> Here is my PKGBUILD for Gazebo:
>
> https://gist.github.com/lyx-x/e6908ef82351b462d4b2e480a43b076c

reference: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gazebo/